# does style class affects child elements of that element?

Tags: html, css

If I style a class of an element. Will that affect the child elements of that element with class
like for example:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <p>Questions? Call 1-866-579-1772</p>
    <div class="footer-cols">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Ways to Watch</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Corporate Information</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Netflix Originals</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Help Center </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"></a>Contact Us</li>
     </ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

Now if I style the class: footer in element footer will that style footer's child elements too?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try out your question? What do you want to style and/or change?

Comment: I want to style anchor element but there are some other link elements in my code too, So how do I style this particular link?

Comment: Some style will be affected (like background-color, font and color) and some will not (like display, padding, margin,...).
Please specify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

Given:

```css
div {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Div content
  <p>P content <input value="an input"></p>
</div>
```

A rule-set consists of a selector and some rules.

The rules will be applied to any element that matches the selector (in this example any `<div>`) unless *another* rule further down [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) overrides it.

An element **might** have the value `inherit` for a property. This means it copies the value from the parent element. Some properties for some elements have `inherit` by default and you can set it explicitly in your rules.

In this example the `<p>` will **not** have a 5 pixel padding because the default `padding` for `<p>` is not `inherit`, but it **will** have yellow text because the default `color` *is* `inherit`.

The background will be rendered in blue, but that is because the default `background-color` for a `<p>` is `transparent` so you can see the div's background colour through it. The `<input>` on the other hand doesn't inherit the `color` or the `padding` and its default `background-color` is `white` so you can't see the blue through it.